# Need C# code for reading multiple attachments from Microsoft Access Attachment data type using DataReader

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I have multiple documents stored in Attachment data type in Access database. Using DataReader, I need to read multiple attachments along with their file name and store them on the file system. Will appreciate your help...

[image]

Comment: What have you tried yourself, and where did it fail? This isnt asking a question, its stating a problem.

Comment: I wonder why this post was closed... Actually, the question is clear here. Shahid needs a solution to get attachments over OLE DB. The problem is it is not easy as the data is stored in Access specific data type column (Attachment type). ADO.NET gets only list of file names separated by semi-colon (just file names and not full paths). Sharid wants to know if it is possible to get **actual** file data (bytes) and full file names so he could restore files on .NET side.

Comment: Attachments are stored within Access database itself and can only be accessed either from the database or by querying System tables (e.g. MSysObjects). Latter is not possible over ADO.NET, I think.<br />I would look at a solution which will involve building a custom file attachment handling on the Access side by storing full file Paths and/or binary data.<br />I am going to give this question a vote up because it is 1)challenging 2)interesting

Comment: @Michael - would you mind re-opening this question, please?

Comment: @IgorTurman: OK, if you can understand it then by all means go ahead.

Comment: Don't use Attachment data type. Its only reason to exist in Access is for compatibility with Sharepoint, and being a multi-value field, it violoates all rules of normalization. Multi-value fields are implemented properly behind the scenes and have a cute UI, but are not easy to deal with in SQL or code, even natively from within Access. Get rid of the attachment field and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only data you get over ADO.NET is **semi-colon delimited list** of attached files' names. Moreover, you will see that ADO.NET recognizes that column type as *String*. So, there is no way you would get the actual binary data from the column (on the .NET side).

I would suggest you not using *Attachment* as data type in Access if you need to access the data from that column outside of Access database. Just create separate table to store all the attachments [links].

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, here's how I solved it using DAO.

```
        var dbe = new DBEngine();
        Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\tmp\access database file.accdb");
        try
        {
            Recordset rstMain = db.OpenRecordset(
                    "SELECT `Attachment` FROM `table name`",
                    RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset);

            while (!rstMain.EOF)
            {
                Recordset2 rstAttach = rstMain.Fields["Attachment"].Value;
                rstAttach.OpenRecordset();

                while (!rstAttach.EOF)
                {
                    Field2 fldAttach = (Field2)rstAttach.Fields["FileData"];
                    string fileName = rstAttach.Fields["FileName"].Value.ToString();
                    fldAttach.SaveToFile(@"C:\tmp\" + fileName);
                    rstAttach.MoveNext();
                }
                rstAttach.Close();
                rstMain.MoveNext();
            }
            rstMain.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

You should include `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;` in the header.

Comment: wow! it really is working. After about half a day of searching and trying everything. Thanks!